# Can't deploy global unit in coreos

Tags: coreos

I'm attempting to deploy a global unit in CoreOS and it's not working. Here's the unit I'm running the test with

```
[Unit]
Description=Global Test

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/true

[X-Fleet]
Global=true
```

When I do

```
fleetctl start global.service
fleetctl list-units
```

I only see one copy of my service running in a cluster with 3 nodes.

Comment: What version of CoreOS (`cat /etc/os-release`)

Comment: It's: CoreOS 410.2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- 410.2.0 does not support global units.
- 435.0.0 instead shipped fleet 0.8.0 that introduced global units.

See

- https://coreos.com/releases/
- https://github.com/coreos/fleet/releases/tag/v0.8.0

Just upgrade to coreos 435.0.0 and everything will work as expected.